# _tkinter.TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?) in a callback with pyepics

Tags: tkinter

I am using a package called pyepics to read a channel from some hardware (say humidity in this case).  This has a feature to run a callback when the value changes.  I would like  to display the new values in a gui.

```
import Tkinter
import epics

global root

class AlarmGUI:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.ending = False

        Tkinter.Label(text="Weather Alarm",bg="AntiqueWhite2",font=("Helvetica", 10,"bold")).grid(row=0,columnspan=2)

        self.grh2l = Tkinter.Label(text='CFHT RH')
        self.grh2l.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=Tkinter.E)

    def cfh(self,value=None,**kw):
        print 'value is',value
        if (value < 80):
            self.grh1 =Tkinter.Label(text=value,bg='Green')
            self.grh1.grid(row=2,column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        elif (value > 80 and value < 85):
            self.grh1 =Tkinter.Label(text=value,bg='Yellow')
            self.grh1.grid(row=2,column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        else:
            self.grh1 =Tkinter.Label(text=value,bg='Red')
            self.grh1.grid(row=2,column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    return gw

def CFHTWeather():
    ag = AlarmGUI(root)
    crh = epics.PV('ws:wsHumid',callback=ag.cfh,auto_monitor=True).get() 

    return cw

def main():
    global root

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.wm_title('Weather Alarms')
    gui = AlarmGUI(root)
    cw = CFHTWeather()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I get a complaint from the line that Tkinter.Label line that should display the new value.

```
  File "./weatherAlarm.py", line 73, in cfh
    self.grh1 =Tkinter.Label(text=value,bg='Red')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2466, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1932, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

If you're interested in the PyEpics info, and PV class I'm using, that is here: http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/pyepics3/

I have seen from other questions about this "out of stack space" that it might be because I'm running another infinite loop.  But I don't understand how my code is doing that - all I want is the gui to change when the channel changes.  Is the callback feature in the PV class an infinite loop itself?

Comment: So, I'm trying to not recreate the widget displaying the value, the Tkinter.Label calls in the if statements.  I put the `Tkinter.Label` in the `__init__` method (with `text=''` just to initialize the widget).  In the `if` statements, I say `self.grh1.configure(text=value,bg='Red')` to change the color based on the logic.  But, I am still having the same trouble with 'out of stack space' error.  Note, this error comes up the first time the callback is used - it does not accumulate after several updates from epics.PY.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the PV class cant say with certainty, but it looks as if you are recreating all of your widgets everytime the callback `ag.cfh` is called and you an see how this would result in an `out of stack space` error.

Instead of recreating the widgets to update their values as it seems you are doing. You should instead move the creation of the label to the `__init__` method with your other widgets then you use `self.grh1['text'] = value` and `self.grh1['background'] = some_color` to update the widgets.

Note, that the background will not automatically change. I'm assuming it does in your case due to the creation of a new widget everytime.

Alternatively you could create  a class attribute to check whether the widget has already been created or not (ie - a counter or boolean) and use an if statement to create the widget only if this counter is less than a specified value or some other appropriate check if you do not wish for the automatic creation of the widget at the start in the `__init__`.

Also, I should note that from the code block you posted it seems that `global root` is redundant there is no need for this`. Additionally, not really an error, but an oddity I find is that you are passing root as the parent and are not specifying the parent in creation of your widgets. What if you passed a tkinter frame as the parent instead? The widgets are being implicitly created to the root window.

Comment: "Note, that the background will not automatically change."  Yes, that's rather essential to it being an alarm - the behavior changes depending on the conditions.

What do you mean by widgets?  The self.[] declarations?

Comment: I mean that when you do `some_widget['background'] = some_color` this does not automatically update the widgets color in tkinter. By widget it is mean labels, radiobuttons, checkboxes, buttons, etc/.